# Is it possible to use bs4's find_all with a regex in the attribute dictionary key?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use bs4 with regex in the `value*` attribute below:

```
all_attributes = [
 <s3><Cell value1="384.01"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value2="447.82"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value3="72.83"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value4="325.65"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value4="49.34"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell Textbox4="filler"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell Textbox4="filler"/></s3>
]
```

The expression I use is:

```
[attribute.find_all("Cell", {re.compile(r'^value[0-9]$'): True})
for attribute in all_attributes]
```

with the hope that I will get the following:

```
[
 <s3><Cell value1="384.01"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value2="447.82"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value3="72.83"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value4="325.65"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value4="49.34"/></s3>
]
```

however I get an empty list.
If I substitute `re.compile(r'^value[0-9]$')` with `value1` or `value2` etc. it works as expected, but obviously not delivering what I want.

I guess using `re.compile` as a dict key does not seem to work, but I don't quite understand why?

Can someone please explain and help find a solution to such a use-case?

Comment: can code like `[ e for e in soup.findAll('cell') if re.search("value\d", str(e))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda function in `.find_all` + `str.startswith`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
 <s3><Cell value1="384.01"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value2="447.82"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value3="72.83"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value4="325.65"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell value4="49.34"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell Textbox4="filler"/></s3>,
 <s3><Cell Textbox4="filler"/></s3>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

x = soup.find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "cell"
    and any(a.startswith("value") for a in tag.attrs)
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```py
[<cell value1="384.01"></cell>, 
 <cell value2="447.82"></cell>, 
 <cell value3="72.83"></cell>, 
 <cell value4="325.65"></cell>, 
 <cell value4="49.34"></cell>]
```

---

Or using regex:

```py
import re

r = re.compile(r"^value\d+")
x = soup.find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "cell" and any(r.search(a) for a in tag.attrs)
)
```